# Changing style in the tabs of the plain ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to build a web app using as starting point the sample ASP.NET Web Application that VS2010 makes available in the Add Projects.  Specifically, I am trying to use the tabbed menu, and change its behavior from the default.  In particular, I am trying to change the tab colors.  Well, this works in the designer.  I can make the tab background white and the foreground red, but when I run the app it displays the tabs in the original drab colors.  It is ignoring the changes I am making to the stylesheet, in other words.  Or so it appears at least.  Is there something I am missing here?

What I want is here:

[image: In designer tab appearance, as changed]

This is what I get, despite my changes to stylesheet:

[image: Still the default appearance when running]

Here is the modified CSS element, which the designer is conforming to, but at run time is being ignored apparently:

```
div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #ff0000;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried refreshing the browser/ clearing the cache?

Comment: That would be too easy. OMG, that did it. Man is that embarrassing. Noob question.  I'm feeling really dumb right about now.  With the evidence displayed here at SO for all to see.

Comment: Dont worry it happens to all of us :)

Comment: A nice trick you can use to prevent caching problems from happening when you are debugging, you can use the query string trick when you link your css:               @{
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
}
<link href="@Url.Content("~/path_to_your_css?" + currentDate)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Wow, @BojinLi, that is slick! Thanks!